# How to target specific wp_nav_menu in function?

Tags: functions, menus

I am adding a specific class on my wp_nav_menu link via function.php but I am not able to target a specific menu: This is what I got which targets all wp_menu_nav on my page:

```
function add_menuclass_active($ulclass) {
 return preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group"', $ulclass, 1);
  }
 add_filter('wp_nav_menu', 'add_menuclass_active');
```

I tried also using the following with no luck

```
function add_menuclass_active( $nav_menu, $args ) {
if( $args->theme_location == 'CUSTOM MENU' )
    return preg_replace( '/<a /', '<a class="list-group"', $nav_menu, 1 );
    return $nav_menu;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'add_menuclass_active', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried the below code and it worked.

Add this to your `functions.php`

```
register_nav_menus(array(
    'top-menu' => __('Menu1', 'twentyfourteen'),
    'side-menu' => __('Menu2', 'twentyfourteen'),
    'footer-menu' => __('Menu3', 'twentyfourteen')
) );

function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

    if ( has_term($menu_locations['top-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ) {
       $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group" ', $item_output, 1);
    }

    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

At last you must select the option "Menu1" for the specific menu on which you have to add the anchor custom classes from dashboard `Apperance->menus`. (select `menu2` or `menu3` for other menus whose anchor links does not need the custom-class)

To add "active class" to the first menu item of the particular menu then try this one:

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

    if ( has_term($menu_locations['top-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ) {
       $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group" ', $item_output, 1);
        if ($item->menu_order == 1){
            $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group active" ', $item_output, 1);
        }
    }

    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

If the active class must be added to the first menu item of all menus then use this:

```
function my_walker_nav_menu_start_el($item_output, $item, $depth, $args) {
    $menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

    if ( has_term($menu_locations['top-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ) {
       $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="list-group" ', $item_output, 1);
    }
    if ($item->menu_order == 1){
        $item_output = preg_replace('/<a /', '<a class="active" ', $item_output, 1);
    }
    return $item_output;
}
add_filter('walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'my_walker_nav_menu_start_el', 10, 4);
```

Comment: I am trying to add a custom class to each LINK in a spacific menu tho. See the code on my question

Comment: ya..okay.. i gave the code to find the specific menu. means instead of $args->theme_location please use get_nav_menu_locations .

Comment: gives this result when doing as you suggest http://pastebin.com/J1fXd6yQ

Comment: @rob.m : i have edited my answer please check it

Comment: what if I wanted to add also a class "active" to the first LINK item only?

Comment: @rob.m : i think its not the first link item but for the current menu link item right??

Comment: yes you're correct. But to be honest it isn't working or maybe I am just doing it wrong. I did not register the menu in function as I simply added add_theme_support('menus'); then created the menu from the panel. You are using a custom walker i believe but this is how I am calling the menu from template http://pastebin.com/ZTZBTVuv

Comment: plz use register_nav_menus in ur functions.php as This function automatically registers custom menu support for the theme therefore you do not need to call add_theme_support( 'menus' ); you dont need to edit the walker in template. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menus

Comment: Ok i have registered the menu but it applies the class to all of the menus I have on the page and not only to a specific one. This is the code http://pastebin.com/2az2Qp0U

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17647/discussion-between-rob-m-and-ammu).

Comment: did u see two options with checkboxes named "videos" and "sites" under the admin panel menus section theme location ?? then if you want to show custom class to videos only then you have to check that "videos" option for that particular menu.

Comment: i have edited my answer for the "active" class insertion

Comment: I'm just curious, the code works, but what does this line mean: `has_term($menu_locations['top-menu'], 'nav_menu', $item) ` ?